# GCP Load Balancer with IAP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, identity-aware-proxy

Is there a way to setup the load balancer so that I can enable IAP without exposing the 443 port of my application?

I would like to accept https requests in the load balancer (just to enable IAP) but only http in my app? How can I add a forwarding rule that forwards from port 433 of the load balancer to port 80/8080 of the backend service?

Comment: Usually, you do not need a forwarding rule unless you are trying to route traffic based on the URL. Do you mean 443 (HTTPS) and not 433? 1) Create a frontend configured for port 443. 2) Create a backend configured for port 80 or 8080. 3) Setup a VPC firewall rule to only allow traffic from the load balancer. 4) What have you tried and what is the problem?

Comment: Why do you want to use IAP?

Comment: I was trying to use without a domain registration and was trying to use the load balancer ip directly.. after I added a domain it worked..